# Trying to keep my Linux fresh

Tags: cleanup

Is this effective?  Is there any danger?

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And then

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

By the way I run my Linux in VMWare

Should I also run Ubuntu Tweak?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't really *need* to clean up after Linux, it deletes the temp files on shutdown. That command only cleans it up for your current session. If you were running a server, or some piece of critical hardware that does not shut down, then I would say it wouldn't hurt to clean it every now and then. Remember, this isn't Microsoft. :)

As for Ubuntu Tweak, I've never used it, although a quick search reveals that it is no longer being maintained. Personally, if a piece of software is no longer being updated and supported, I get rid of it.

Hope that helps!